# Why was model.save needed on heroku but not on localhost in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I've been developing a Rails application to deploy on Heroku. It involves a `User` object and a `Card` object, where a `User` `has_many` `Cards` and a `Card` `belongs_to` a `User`. I've written actions to attach a `Card` to a `User` and `detach` a `Card` from a `User`.

It does this with `@user.cards << @card`, which I found works fine when running my Rails application on my dev machine (my app acts as if `@user.cards` contains `@card` and `@card.user_id` = `@user.id`, but when I deploy to Heroku I found I needed to do both `@user.cards << @card` and `@user.save` to actually reflect the change. What would be the reason for the difference? Does Heroku do some sort of caching I'm not aware of?

Comment: Maybe it's a difference between MySQL (probably what you're using locally) and Postgres (which runs on Heroku).

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: I'm using Postgres on both development and production.

Comment: perhaps it's a difference between production/development environments?   Caching perhaps, what if you do @user.reload! after you've added the card.